# Spring Boot Actuator + Java Melody

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, java-melody

I'm using the actuator sub project in my spring boot application. I configured the address and the port of the actuator management functions in the `application.properties` to separate the monitoring traffic from the production traffic.

```
management.address=127.0.0.1
management.port=8081
```

Additionally I want to use java melody and I want to provide the java melody dashboard on the same connection pool as the actuator endpoints. So finally the java melody dashboard should be provided by `localhost:8081/monitoring`, not(!) by `localhost:8080/monitoring`.

How can I do that?

Comment: I believe you need to set up a controller with an explicit mapping to do that.

Comment: Did you find any way to do this?

Comment: Yes and no. It is possible to separate Java melody from the application. But this also affects the monitoring. Java Melody injects itself into the request pipeline to monitor the application. If you isolate Java Melody in the same way as Spring Actuator, a monitoring of the application is no longer possible, because the application request a processes by a request pipeline, Java Melody cannot access. So now Java Melody uses it's own network port, but it's also useless, because it can't monitor the application. It seems, that there is no good way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the spring-boot management port (e.g. 8081) for the monitoring page instead of the application http port (e.g. 8080), since javamelody-spring-boot-starter 1.76.

See doc:
https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/wiki/SpringBootStarter#configuration-in-case-of-management-port